# Animation Button that scales and surround with circle

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

For some reason, 
I feel this kind of UI and it's interactive way
is highly profound and intuitive.
(Below picture shows the specific App).

Mainly speak,

1. when the user enters the screen,
   the Scan button would scale out and back,
   acting like a heartbeat, which gives the user an intention to click the button.
2. the button not only scale out but with a circle surround it, looks just like the ripple in the water.

Here comes the question of implementing these technique on Android UI,
I had do some survey and found that:

for UI component to scale out we can use `android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation`,
But how could I possible to draw a ripple that will surround the button while it scaling out?

Could anyone give me some advice of doing these kind of tasks?
Namely "the website resources", "Github", "Framework" or "API reference"?

I've already decompiler the apk and give up when I saw only mess code there
(I think due to the Proguard or something that protect peeking from decompile)

[image: Round Button with circle around]

[image: Round Button that scale]

Comment: use framelayout, the button animated with ```scaleanimation```, and the imageview with the circle behind the button animated with ```scaleanimation``` and ```rotateanimation```.

Comment: @user3482468 post your xml